# MVC J2EE web application without framework

Tags: jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

I am new for java web applications, I would like to know which is best way to develop controller to handle request from user routed through single page like I have index.jsp page which offers log in and new registration for user, how I can handle it through single controller with all database look ups and directing to respective view.

Answer (score 0):

What is your reason for not wanting to use a framework? You should look in spring-mvc its very powerfull and there is no need to reinvent the wheel? Spring can handle everything you need.

Comment: Joey thanks for reply, Yes I am moving towards frameworks. Can you suggest me which one would be more suitable for this case Spring or Struts 2.0